drag and drop task in react js using buttons
In drag and drop if we have to do selection first and after that have to submit by clicking button so what type of functions or event handlers I have to use?
I have tried react-beautiful-dnd but still I am not having satisfied answer.
I have this output

You should share you code, not a picture. Preferably use the <> button in the editor for the question, and then you can add HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

To clarify the use case: An element should be created in the target area as a copy of an element in the source area. The user should be able to drag and drop the element OR select the same element from source and click a button to copy it to the target. Is that right? Create a function that can do the copying regardless of what the user can do, like function copyElement(source_element, target){...} and then call this function either based on the user dragging, clicking or something third.

Here is a working example. The function copy_element(id) handles the copying of the item. This function is either called on a drop event or when the copybtn is clicked.


const source = document.getElementById('source');
const target = document.getElementById('target');
const copy = document.forms.copyform;

source.addEventListener('dragstart', e => {
  let id = e.target.closest('.item').dataset.id;
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', id);
});

target.addEventListener('dragover', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
});

target.addEventListener('drop', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let id = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
  copy_element(id);
});

source.addEventListener('change', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  form.copybtn.disabled = !form.item.value;
});

copy.copybtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let id = e.target.form.item.value;
  copy_element(id);
});

function copy_element(id) {
  // copy the item from source
  let item = source.querySelector(`div[data-id = "${id}"]`);
  let clone = item.cloneNode(true);
  clone.draggable = false;
  // append the copy to target
  target.append(clone);
  // unselect the item and disable the copy button
  [...copy.elements].forEach(input => input.checked = false);
  copy.copybtn.disabled = true;
}
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  gap: 1em;
}

#source {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  border: solid thin gray;
  min-height: 300px;
}

section#target {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 3;
  border: solid thin gray;
  min-height: 300px;
}

div.item {
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin: .3em;
  padding: .3em;
  min-height: 3em;
}

#source input {
  display: none;
}

#source input:checked~.item {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
<section id="source">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="item" value="item1" form="copyform" required>
    <div class="item" data-id="item1" draggable="true">Some element</div>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="item" value="item2" form="copyform">
    <div class="item" data-id="item2" draggable="true">Another element</div>
  </label>
</section>
<form id="copyform">
  <button name="copybtn" type="button" disabled>>></button>
</form>
<section id="target"></section>



